# mixed effect model question

Tags: regression, machine-learning, mixed-model, computational-statistics, mixed-type-data

Hi i have a certain task i want to solve:

For two months, participants played an app, in which they played 5 different therapeutic games (TGs). At the beginning of each session, they also completed a 5-scale State-of-Mind questionnaire, rating the extent to which they feel tired (or rested), distracted (or focused), cautious (or adventurous), sad (or happy), and hungry (or full). Scores range from -1 to 1.

Leverage playing data (time & levels played in each TG in each session) to predict/model changes in the participant’s state of mind

and a data set which contains these columns: Index(['Participant #', 'date', 'time_tg1', 'time_tg2', 'time_tg3', 'time_tg4', 'time_tg5', 'levels_tg1', 'levels_tg2', 'levels_tg3', 'levels_tg4', 'levels_tg5', 'rested', 'focused', 'adventaurous', 'happy', 'full', 'day of use']

I am not sure regarding the level columns if they are categorial or not.

after centering and removing outliers i tried with rpy2 in order to add 2 random effects (participant + day of use):

model_formula <- 'happy ~ time_tg1 + C(levels_tg1)+time_tg1:C(levels_tg1)+ time_tg2 + C(levels_tg2) + time_tg2:C(levels_tg2)+ time_tg3 +C(levels_tg3) + time_tg3:C(levels_tg3)+ time_tg4 + C(levels_tg4)+time_tg4:C(levels_tg4)+time_tg5 +C(levels_tg5)+time_tg5:C(levels_tg5)+(1|Participant_) + (1|day_of_use)

i am not sure if this correct/incorrect way or there is a better approach

Comment: Why is day of use a random effect?  I'm not saying it's wrong to do that, but it strikes me as a fixed effect.

Comment: that's what i am wondering as well.
and i was wandering if i should check the interaction of day of use with  the other variables.
i remove C from levels as well.
should i make some kind of manipulation in order to add the day of use to the regression?

Comment: What exactly are the `time_tgX` variables ? Are these the duration of each playing session, or the time during the day that the session occurred, or ??

Comment: session duration